# Refer to multiple dynamic named ranges as array value in range

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have two named dynamic ranges, one named 'DRange1' with the formula

```
='Sheet1'!$A$2:INDEX('Sheet1'!$A$2:$A$5000,COUNTA('Sheet1'!$A$2:$A$5000))
```

and one named 'DRange2' with the formula

```
='Sheet2'!$A$2:INDEX('Sheet2'!$A$2:$A$5000,COUNTA('Sheet2'!$A$2:$A$5000))
```

both ranges work and give proper values. Then I want to display the values of those ranges in a single range with the address `'Sheet3'!A2:A10000`.

Entering an array formula akin to `{=DRange1,DRange2}` does not work and gives a `#VALUE` error. Using a named range to combine the dynamic ranges does not work either. Does anyone have a solution to this?

I highly prefer a non-VBA solution since I can't run code in this book. Thanks.